# ignoe/bypass the key if value is nil after decoder in swift

Tags: json, swift, codable, decodable, encodable

My process is I have bunch of json string that I need to convert into request payload and make a POST request to api call. The issue is key may or may not exist from my original json string and the API does not accept nil as value. So the API call failed after decode if the key does not exist.
The snippet code from mine is like following
I transfer into decoable type. I search online and found the way `decodeIfPresent` in swift5 How can I do it?

```
struct Student: Codable {
    var name: String
    var skill: String?

    public enum Student: String, CodingKey {
        case name
        case skill
    }

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: Student.self)
        self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        self.skill = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .skill)
    }
}
let testString = "{\"name\": \"withSkill\", \"skill\": \"yell\"}"
let testStringB = "{\"name\": \"no Skill\"}"
let data = testString.data(using: .utf8)!
let dataB = testStringB.data(using: .utf8)!
let decodeData = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Student.self, from: data)
let decodeDataB = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Student.self, from: dataB)
```

```
/// what I get
▿ Optional<Student>
    ▿ some : Student
        - name : "no Skill"
        - skill : nil

/// what I want
▿ Optional<Student>
    ▿ some : Student
        - name : "no Skill"
```

Comment: It's unclear what you want. Do you understand that once you declared the `Student` struct like that, then it must have a `skill` property, and it must have a value? (nil or otherwise)

Comment: since my request json may or may not have key `skill` without declaring as optional then how should i do it?

Comment: What's wrong with declaring as optional? What's wrong with `skill` being nil?

Comment: The request does not accept value as nil. So if the value is nil I have to filter out the key

Comment: "The request does not accept value as nil. So if the value is nil I have to filter out the key – " What request? Are you more interested in Encoding? If so when a value is nil, you can decide to not put it into the JSON.

Comment: @Larme, my process is I have bunch of json string that I need to convert into request payload and make a post request to api call. m tissue here is key may or may not exist from my original json string. the api does not accept nil so call failed after decode if the key does not exist

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58809868/how-to-remove-data-model-nil-fields-from-custom-encoded-decoded-json-in-swift ? So it's about encoding, not decoding...

Comment: hm. how the above is different than I have?

Comment: Your issue is about sending to an API encoded JSON where you ignore keys which have `nil` values. Then you need to focus on `func encode(to encoder: Encoder)`, not `decode(from:)`...

Comment: @jacobcan118 Actually, the default encode implementation automatically discards properties with type `nil`, so they don't appear in the data. Does the behaviour you're seeing not match that?